# mysql timestamp and php query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database. All the fields, I assign and I have a datestamp for my date field.
it automatically generates `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` like this `2011-11-21 21:31:37`
However, I would like it to do so in two diffrent columns:

A date field with `YYYY-MM-DD` or `2011-11-21`

A time field with `HH:MM:SS` or `21:31:37`

This is my insert php code

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO  `db`.`table` (`id` ,`fkid` ,`paid` ,`date`)
VALUES (NULL, '$userid', '0', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
```

I have tried CURRENT_DATESTAMP and it does not work.

The 2nd part of the question is: how to I make the table so it works with the proper code? Should the structure of the of the field be type text, or date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not recommend splitting your timestamp into separate date and time columns. Instead, it is easiest to use a `DATETIME` column, and query it for its date and time portions using the MySQL functions `DATE()` and `TIME()`:

```
SELECT DATE(`date`) AS d, TIME(`date`) AS t FROM db.dable;
```

When inserting, you can use the `NOW()` function to set the current timestamp.  `` `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() `` is a synonym for `NOW()`.

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO  `db`.`table` (`id` ,`fkid` ,`paid` ,`date`)VALUES (NULL ,  '$userid',  '0', NOW());";
```

Comment: How can I then compare the what d returns to the current date